# Unable to load DLL python module in PyCharm. Works fine in Jupyter and Spyder

Tags: python, dll, pycharm

Unable to load `DLL` python module in `PyCharm`. Works fine in `Jupyter` and `Spyder`.

I am currently working on twitter data analysis. importing twitter and `json` works just fine in both `Jupyter` notebook and `Spyder`. I tried it on Pycharm, it returns :

```
import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate

ImportError: DLL load failed:
```

I tried setting path variable to `C:\Users\douny\Anaconda3\DLLs` but still not working.

How can I fix this issue? To be clear, I installed Anaconda Navigator first, then I installed Pycharm after and using window 10 64.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have both 32-bit and 64-bit installations of Python installed. 64-bit Python interpreters cannot load 32-bit DLLs, and vice versa.

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you for the comment. As far as I am concerned, I have installed both Anaconda and Pycharm 64 bit version. It works just fine with every other environment except Pycharm.

Comment: Which suggests that PyCharm is running a different interpreter from the other environments. Check your PyCharm project settings.

Comment: @BoarGules I checked and it says its project interpreter is Python 3.7 (Anaconda3\ python.exe).

Comment: And are you very sure that you don't have both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of Anaconda installed?

Comment: @BoarGules Yes. It says Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 11 2019, 14:11:50) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on win32. And Pycharm is 64 as well...

Comment: Only what PyCharm says is important because only PyCharm is giving you trouble. Running Anaconda (where it works), and asking it what version it is, only confirms what you already know. I think PyCharm is running a *different* version of Python 3.7.2. You will get the error you report if PyCharm is running a 32-bit interpreter and the others are not. And it is entirely possible for 64-bit PyCharm to run a 32-bit Python interpreter.

Comment: Try PyCharm 2019.1 https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/, there is a known similar issue fixed there https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27234

Comment: @PavelKarateev Thanks! I uninstalled previous version of pycharm and tried the one you suggested. It works fine for now.